# Calling a vector from a string

Tags: string, matlab, vector, data-structures

I am attempting to write an algorithm that selects a specific reference standard (vector) as a function of temperature.  The temperature values are stored in a structure ( `procspectra(i).temperature` ).  My reference standards are stored in another structure ( `standards.interp.zeroed.ClOxxx` ) where xxx are numbers such as 200, 210, 220, etc.  I have built the rounding construct and paste it below.

```
for i = 1:length(procspectra);
if mod(-procspectra(i).temperature,10) > mod(procspectra(i).temperature,10);
    %if mod(-) > mod(+) round down, else round up
    tempvector(i) = procspectra(i).temperature - mod(procspectra(i).temperature,10);
else
    tempvector(i) = procspectra(i).temperature + mod(-procspectra(i).temperature,10);
end
clostd =  strcat('standards.interp.zeroed.ClO',num2str(tempvector(i)));
end
```

This construct works well.  Now, I have built a string which is identical to the name of the vector I want to invoke, but I'm uncertain how to actually call the vector given that this is encoded as a string.  Ideally I want to do something within the for-loop like:

```
parameters(i).standards.ClOstandard = clostd
```

where I actually am assigning that parameter structure to be the same as the vector I have saved in the standards structure I have previously generated (and not just a string)

Could anyone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't construct `clostd` like that (containing the full variable name), make it contain only the last field name instead:

```
clostd = ['ClO' num2str(tempvector(i))];
parameters(i).standards.ClOstandard = standards.interp.zeroed.(clostd);
```

This is the syntax of accessing a structure's field dynamically, using a string. So the following three are equivalent:

```
struc.Cl0123
struc.('Cl0123')
fieldn='Cl0123'; struc.(fieldn)
```

Comment: @user8307 no problem:)